# String aggregation in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I have a collection of documents as follows:

```
{
    "id": ...,
    "key": 47
},
{
    "id": ...,
    "key": 12
}
```

I want to aggregate the whole collection to a single string, by concatenating the keys, delimited by `|`. So here, the output would be the string `47|12`. I don't mind an additional `|` at the end, if that makes things easier.

How is this done in MongoDB aggregation pipelines? I am coming from SQL and in PostgreSQL, this would look like `select string_agg(key, "|" order by id) from my_table`.

I think I can make this work by first aggregating the collection to an array and then applying `$reduce` with the `$concat` function on the single array, but I am not sure if this is the best solution, as aggregating first to an array *feels wrong*. Is there a way to reduce immediately on the collection instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The desired result can be achieved by using the `$group` stage with `$push` to create an array of all keys. After that, use `$reduce` to concatenate the keys with the desired delimiter.

Example with delimeter `"|"`:

```json
[
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "keys": { "$push": "$key" }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "concatenatedKeys": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$keys",
          "initialValue": "",
          "in": { "$concat": ["$$value", "|", { "$toString": "$$this" }] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

In the end `$toString` converts each key to a string before concatenation. This may be omitted if all keys are of string type.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. I am wondering if first grouping to an array is the "canonical" approach in MongoDB for this kind of problems. This looks odd to me, as I assume this has some overhead, but I might be completely off here, as I am coming from a SQL mindset.

Comment: In MongoDB, using the `$group` stage to aggregate documents into an array is a common approach for certain types of transformations. While it may seem unusual for SQL where set-based operations are more prevalent, in MongoDB's document-based paradigm, working with arrays is often efficient.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB is a NoSQL DB and by design you should only be querying a single row by ID, and all aggregations are meant to be separately. E.g. during write time.

[$concat](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/) will not really work for you since it aggregates values within a single row.

I think in your case it's very simple to get all the results and then concatenate at the client side.

E.g. JavaScript / NodeJS:

```js
function concatKeys(input) {
    return (input || []).map(({key}) => key).join("|")
}
```